# SQL tables compare to only 1 row that is duplicated

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables, 2 tables (TableB, TableC) have the same recorded data. TableA TableB and C are created after SUMing / casting seconds into HH:mm:ss from another table. However TableA has duplicates of names as it calculates login times which 1 person can log more than once a day where as the other 2 are totals in seconds converted. Is there a way that I compare Table A with B and C taking only 1 name of the duplicates from A? Basically if TableA shows an incident for Tim Smith at 6AM and again for 12PM take those separate rows and just display his name once with a 2 instead?

Here is what TableA looks like:

[image]

The WHOLE SQL command I use is:

```
SELECT TableD.[Name], RIGHT('0' + CAST(TableD.[Staffed Time] / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((TableD.[Staffed Time] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(TableD.[Staffed Time] % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
AS StaffedTime, RIGHT('0' + CAST(TableD.[Time in Break] / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((TableD.[Time in Break] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(TableD.[Time in Break] % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) 
AS BreakTime, RIGHT('0' + CAST(TableD.[Time in Lunch] / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((TableD.[Time in Lunch] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(TableD.[Time in Lunch] % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) 
AS LunchTime

INTO TableE
FROM TableD

SELECT [Name], LunchTime,
        case
          when LunchTime < '01:04:00' then 0

          else 1
        end as LunchInc
into TableB
FROM TableE

SELECT [Name], BreakTime,
        case
          when BreakTime BETWEEN '00:29:00' AND '00:40:00' then 0

          else 1
        end as BreakInc
into TableC
FROM TableE

SELECT TableG.[Name], TableG.[Login Time]
,      case 
            when ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TableG.[Login Time], TableF.StartTime)) BETWEEN 0 and 4 then 0 else 1
       end as LoginInc 
into TableA 
FROM TableG
JOIN TableF 
  on TableG.[Agent Name] = TableF.AgentName
```

If I were to add the Login Time to the select command at the top when it is doing the casting, it will return thousands of lines of data which is completely inaccurate, or at least for the way I need it to work.

Here is what I've tried.

```
 SELECT TableD.[Name], TableG.[Name], RIGHT('0' + CAST(TableD.[Staffed Time] / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((TableD.[Staffed Time] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(TableD.[Staffed Time] % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
AS StaffedTime, RIGHT('0' + CAST(TableD.[Time in Break] / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((TableD.[Time in Break] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(TableD.[Time in Break] % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) 
AS BreakTime, RIGHT('0' + CAST(tacmain.[Time in Lunch] / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((TableD.[Time in Lunch] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(TableD.[Time in Lunch] % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) 
AS LunchTime

INTO TableE
FROM TableD, TableG
INNER JOIN TableG.[Name] = TableD.[Name]
```

In hopes that it will match the names together and throw in the login times with TableE, this is where it added thousands of lines of data.

Comment: Please show the table structure, some sample data, what you have tried, the results you get and the results you want to get.  Then we have a far better chance of helping you.  Right now I can't really understand what you want.

Comment: Certainly, will add it to my question give me a few.

Comment: Sure there are lots of ways.   The most promising, probably, is using a CTE or derived table in place of a direct join to Table A.

Comment: Notice TableA B and C are made from the outcome of G and E